# Prevent Google's indexer thinking my incidental <video> tags are what the page is about?

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I recently updated a client's homepage. There are four tiny mp4 `<video>` instances on loop. I could have used another format (eg animated webp in an `<img>`) but we found mp4 gave the best device support and bitrate.

A few hours after uploading, I got an email from Google search console:

> #### Video page indexing issues detected in [homepage URL]
>
> Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 2 Video page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site. We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.
>
> Top issues
>
> - No thumbnail URL provided
> - Google could not determine the prominent video on the page

Google seems to be treating these Videos as *what the page is about*, when that's really about as far from the truth as possible. They're a tiny fragment. **I want Google to ignore these videos.** They're set dressing. I *could* give them thumbnails but if they started showing up as the search result, that would be even worse.

I would be all for ignoring this, but the [natural] assumption from the client was that this was the end of the world, and that they weren't being indexed at all.

So is there any way I can attribute the video to suggest that it's unimportant?